# Do native speakers read "seemed to" omit the "ed"?

Tags: pronunciation

[sound example](https://forvo.com/phrase/it_seemed_to_exhale_a_silent_and_calm_authority/)

I have heard many times of the omitting of the "ed".
But someone suggested that it should never omit the ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can sound like the /d/ is omitted in this context. This is an example of the so-called "elision" of alveolar plosives in English, as described in Araucaria's answer to the ELU question [Pronunciation Deleting /t/ Between Consonants](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259068/pronunciation-deleting-t-between-consonants?noredirect=1&lq=1). Even native speakers may not be able to distinguish a /d/ or /t/ sound from no sound in this kind of context. But a native speaker's ears will usually automatically fill in hard-to-hear sounds like this based on grammar and meaning.

Even if you can't hear it, it may actually be present in the speaker's tongue movements--see user6726's answer to this Linguistics SE question: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/28276/what-books-give-a-comprehensive-analysis-of-intermorphemic-consonant-clusters-in. I would not recommend that a learner try to omit /d/ entirely in this context.